# El metodo put no me actualiza la base de datos

Tags: reactjs, axios, function, crud

```
 const updateData = (data) => {
    let endpoint = `${url}/${data.id}`
    let options = {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {"Content-type" : "application/json"}};
    axios(endpoint, options)
.then(res=>{   
 let newData = Db.map((el)=> el.id === data.id ? data : el)
 setDb(newData)
    } )}
```

Buenas tardes. Al principio, el metodo **PUT** me carga el contenido, pero cuando la actualizo con **f5**, se me borra. ¿Alguien sabe como resolver el problema?

Esto me aparece como error en la consola del navegador:

> react_devtools_backend.js:4045 Warning: Encountered two children with
> the same key, `null`. Keys should be unique so that components
> maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause
> children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported
> and could change in a future version.

Comment: El warning tiene relación con el JSX, muéstranos lo que hay en el return. Por otro lado, después de que se aplica PUT, y se asigna el estado newData, debes tener un método que al dar f5 traiga la información actualizada de tu endpoint (la info que recién se actualizo con PUT), esta información debe estar de alguna forma conectada al mismo estado `newData`. Sería de ayuda ver el componente completo o un ejemplo mínimo.

Comment: Gracias. El problema era que en vez de body, debia escribir data

Comment: @Maxi71237584 pon eso como respuesta. Y si encontraste la solución en alguna página (a ser posible algo oficial), enlázala como referencia.